# Can we modify the weight function of particle filters?

Tags: particle-filter

I am doing some experiments on particle filtering and I have a problem calculating the weights. Normally, the weights should be decided based on a function $w_{s_t}=p(z_t|s_t)$, if this distribution is normal, then $w_{s_t}\propto \exp(-1/2(z_t-s_t)'\Gamma^{-1}(z_t-s_t))$, where $\Gamma$ is the covariance matrix.

But in my case, $\Gamma$ is very small in scale. Then all the $w_{s_t}$ are zeros when I compute using Matlab. So I am wondering, can I modify the distribution by changing a different $\Gamma$? For example, let  $\Gamma=I$, an identity matrix, then $w_{s_t}\propto exp(-1/2(z_t-s_t)'(z_t-s_t))$. In this way, the all the weights are non-zero and can be compared.

Answer (score 1):

Let $x_{s_t}=−0.5\cdot (z_t−s_t)′Γ^{−1}(z_t−s_t)$. I suggest you to:

1. compute all the log weights $x_{s_t}$, then compute $x_{max}=\max_t x_{s_t}$.
2. compute the weights as $w_{s_t}=\exp{(x_{s_t}-x_{max})}$.

As the weights are computed up to multiplicative constant this works and allows to exponentiate non too small values so that the weights are computed with a good accuracy (allowing them to be non zero, at least, for the highest one).

I think that it will solve your problem. Changing the formula for the weights without changing the proposal is not correct.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion and I am testing this method. I found this paper: http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/Xplore/defdeny.jsp?url=http%3A%2F%2Fieeexplore.ieee.org%2Fstamp%2Fstamp.jsp%3Ftp%3D%26arnumber%3D7079001%26userType%3Dinst&denyReason=-134&arnumber=7079001&productsMatched=null&userType=inst. On paper 81, there is a generalized resampling. I am thinking if I set $\Gamma=I$, is it equivalent with applying a generalized resampling. That is, I set $w_{s_t}=\tilde{w}_{s_t}^{\alpha}=(exp(-0.5(z_t-s_t)'(z_t-s_t)))^{\alpha}$, where $\Gamma=1/\alpha I$.

Comment: I quickly read about generalized resampling and I think that you miss the fact that resampling is different from estimating the weights and whatever the way you resample you need to estimate the weights and this can anly be done according to the weighting formula which in your case consists of the likelihood. The solution I give you allow you to compute the weights appropriately (don't forget to mark the answer as accepted if it actually works). Hope it helps.

Comment: I tried your idea. But I got almost all zero weights as well and only one 1, which is the weight of $x_{max}$. In my case, all $x_{s_t}$ are between $-6\times 10^{7}$ to $-2\times 10^7$. What I suggested is, in principle, we calculate the weights first and then we do resampling. But in practice, we do the two steps together.

Comment: Sorry, I am not sure to follow you. What I can say is that the weights must be computed using to the covariance matrix of your statistial model: $\Sigma$. Then you can use another density to resample the particles (as in eneralized resampling). The fact that most of the particles have weights 0 compared to a very few has weights close to one simply says that the 0 weights particles are very unlikely compared to those having weights close to one. So they must have very small weights compared to the other (say it is $10^{-10}$ if you prefer something different from 0). Hope it helps.

Comment: I think I finally solve the problem by using vpa in Matlab. In this way, I can keep the extremely small numbers instead of zero. Thank you for your patient.